# How to change the order of the form fields of the catalog advanced search form

Tags: magento-1.9, advanced-search

I have added a couple of custom attributes to the catalog advanced search form, but they appear in the order you add them. With the last attribute added at the bottom of the form. I would like to change the order of form fields to make it a bit more intuitive for my visitors. How can I do this?

Comment: How did you added the attributes?

Comment: I added the attributes through Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes. And I set the property "Use in Advanced Search" to Yes.

Comment: Have you tried to set the position field of the attribute? At the same page where you set "use in advanced search"?

Comment: The position field is not editable. It is only editable when you use the attribute in Layered Navigation. And the field 'Use In Layered Navigation' is only editable with catalog input type Dropdown, Multiple Select and Price. And my catalog input type is a text area and text fields.

Answer (score 1):

The advanced form in the base template is in the file `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalogsearch/advanced/form.phtml` and it loads the attributes to show as part for a foreach loop.

It uses the function call `Mage_CatalogSearch_Block_Advanced_Form::getSearchableAttributes` to load the attributes. Which intern loads a collection of attributes with the filter use in advanced search but sadly only uses attribute id as the order.

```
->setOrder('main_table.attribute_id', 'asc')
```

I see you have two options:

1. Extend `Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Advanced::getAttributes` and set your own order in the collection. You could extend the attribute table to have a new column to order attribute by.
2. Extend `Mage_CatalogSearch_Block_Advanced_Form::getSearchableAttributes` and perform some form of processing on the attributes so that they appear in the order that you desire.

For me option 1 would be the cleanest and you could extend the system so that the admin user could specify the order they want, but it would also be the most work.